# How to use variable as a part of the object property name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, properties

I'd like to use "param" as a part of the object property name in following code:

In php I'd it would look like this:
   $paramvalue = object.$$param;

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function UpdateValue(object,param) {
        data = object.getRow().getData();
    var paramvalue = object.missing_part_like_$$param;
    console.log("Parameter " + param + " updated, value: " + paramvalue ); 
}
```

In other words, if the sent parameter is "dimension" what I need to get is:

```
var paramvalue = object.dimension;
```

How do I do the same in Javascript?

Comment: Solutions in "duplicate answers" show how to combine fixed string and variable, not how to use variable as a part of object property name used to pull property value.